# jQuery: How to catch change event from input[type='checkbox'] if it was checked programmatically?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I've got an `<input type="checkbox" id="check1" />`.
How to catch `change` event for this checkbox if it was changed from script i.e. `$('#check1').attr('checked', 'checked');`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript doesn't fire events based on programmatic changes to form elements - to prevent infinite loops of events - so you have two (less-than-ideal) options:

- Write a wrapper function which changes the attribute *and* calls your callback, and then force yourself to always use your wrapper function
- Just call the callback yourself when you change the attribute

Comment: If *you* changed the checkbox progammatically, then you can trigger the change event yourself. E.g., $("#myCheckbox").prop("checked", true).trigger("change").

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you are expecting **[this](http://www.jsfiddle.net/DCwuT/)**

Comment: Not really. I'm expecting that execution of code `$('#check1').attr('checked', 'checked');` will fire `change()` event for that checkbox.

Answer (score -1):

[**This**](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) might be what you were looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function(){          
   $('#check1').click(function(){
      var n = $("#check1:checked").length;  
      alert(n);
   });
});
```